# How to add MySQL table to Object Relational Designer in VS 2013?

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

Connection is established; and table is visible in the list of tables in Server Explorer for MySQL database.

However, when I try to drag and drop it to Object Relational Designer, nothing happens.

What should I change to be able to use designer for MySQL table?

Answer (score 0):

Try using VS2012 if you can.  The Object Relational Designer in VS causes so many issues for me we have to use VS2012 to be able to update our dbml objects.